# Ruby Method definition Syntax with & keyword

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

```
class ExchangeUtil
  def exchange_to(other_currency, date = Date.current, &)
      @bank.exchange_with_on(self, other_currency, date, &)
  end
end
```

What is the siginificance of ***&*** in method definition and method calls?

Comment: & is normally used to pass blocks around,  so typically you would see &some_variable_name  and not just &.  I would think that & without a variable name would be a syntax error.

Comment: @nPn I thought so too. Apparently, I just wasn't ready to see Ruby 3.1 syntax out in the wild.

Answer (score 1):

It's a new feature in Ruby 3.1: [Anonymous block argument](https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubychanges/3.1.html#anonymous-block-argument)

It's just a shortcut for when you have a block argument for a function whose only purpose is to be passed to another function. Older syntax for that would've been

```rb
class ExchangeUtil
  def exchange_to(other_currency, date = Date.current, &block)
      @bank.exchange_with_on(self, other_currency, date, &block)
  end
end
```

The param `&block` could've had any name, like `&my_block`, but the name was generally meaningless, so they made it "anonymous".